# How can I add a hyperlink to this email being created in Android app?

Tags: java, android, html, email

I would like to add a hyperlink to an email message which I will be creating as below.
How could this be completed? I have tried various attempts to set as HTML which have been unsuccesful.

```
            String message =  "\n\n <a href=\"www.apple.com\">Click Here to Open</a>";

            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ selectedEmail});
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject );
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message));
            email.setType("message/rfc822");

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client:"));
```

Comment: Try including `http://` in the url

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to include HTML in a java file, it will not work.
For your purpose, you need to create a *textView* with the text as "click here to open" and to it attach an *onClickListener()* within which you can start your intent.

Comment: I am trying to use the hyperlink in an email not from within th app